# Can I use the USB port of a router configured as AP to retrieve files from network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, usb, usb-flash-drive, wireless-access-point

I have a CNC laser cutting machine that reads the files to be cut from an USB Flash Drive.

In my home network the main router has a flash drive on it's USB port that I use to share files over the network.

So my question is, can I use a second router configured as AP to retrieve files from the network and connect it's USB port to my laser cutter? The diagram would be something like this:

[Connection Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZPHt.png)

I know there are modern laser cutters with embedded wifi or ethernet ports but it would be a lot cooler and cheaper if a solution ike this worked!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

USB works differently for the host and peripheral sides.  The chipsets that drive the ports are different as well.  A host-host connection won't work.  You can't change a host chipset to a peripheral chipset without physically changing hardware and the drivers on the devices that talk to the hardware.

Newer USB standards blur this a bit, but it's unlikely the router or your CNC machine has the hardware or software support for it.